# Append extension to output of os.environ.get

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a json file named after an environment variable.

The variable is called `parent` with the value `galaxy`

This is what my file looks like.

```
import json
import sys
import os

Report = os.environ.get('MainReport')

if Report == "Main":
    newFile = os.environ.get('parent')
else:
    newFile = os.environ.get('child')

#####Additional Logic Here############

json_output = json.dumps(output,indent=4)
with open(newFile, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_output)

print("Output file is generated in the current directory!")
file.close()
```

When I run the script, it creates the file `galaxy` in my current directory as expected.

But I need the file to be named `galaxy.json`

I've tried

```
if Report == "Main":
    newFile = os.environ.get('parent').json
```

But it throws this error
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'`

Is there a way to append `.json` to the output from `os.environ.get`

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 5):

Use the concatenation operator to append a string.

```
if Report == "Main":
    newFile = os.environ.get('parent') + ".json"
```